# Facebook Share preview showing CSS

Tags: facebook, wordpress

Hey everyone I was working on a Wordpress site in a dev environment and when I shared a page on Facebook I would see a nice preview image and some of the text.  When I moved the site to production now I don't see the image and the preview text is a bunch of CSS code.

Here are two links to test with

Dev - http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fssb.thejspot.ws&title=Sunset+Beach+Golf+Company
Live - http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fssbeachgolf.com&title=Sunset+Beach+Golf+Company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any open graph tags defined for either site. You're lucky on the dev site that you were getting what you want.

Either code the open graph tags into your theme or get a plugin (I like Wordpress SEO) that adds the tags for you.

Also, take a look at the output from the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) for each of your URLs. That is the first place you should start when you're not getting the results you want.